# PCRE based Regex for redirection

Tags: regex, replace, conditional-statements, pcre

I have some links as follow.

```
http://www.example.com/excel.aspx
http://www.example.com:80/word.aspx
http://www.example.com:80/powerpoint.aspx
http://www.example.com:80/pdf.aspx
http://www.example.com:80/barcode.aspx
http://www.example.com/ocr.aspx
http://www.example.com/email.aspx
http://www.example.com/project.aspx
```

& I want to rewrite the URLs as following in a single regex pattern or single regex line.

```
https://www.example.com/excel
https://www.example.com/word
https://www.example.com/powerpoint
https://www.example.com/pdf
https://www.example.com/barcode
https://www.example.com/ocr
https://www.example.com/outlook
https://www.example.com/project
```

If you check & compare, I have replaced email with outlook in substitution URL.

I can match patterns as follow **.*/(\w+).aspx** and substitute as **https://www.example.com/$1** but I cannot find a way to replace **email** with **outlook**. Demo https://regex101.com/r/71huIx/24

Something similar to http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-conditional-replacement.html but without a pool or dictionary. However, if the pool or dictionary can be part of regex itself then it will OK. Reason being, I have txt file with rules, where line1 is regex & line2 is a substitution.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe do it in two regular expressions instead of one? First normalize and strip `.aspx`, second, redirect email to `outlook`. That makes things much easier.

Comment: @Corion, Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, that is one solution, however, better to do it in a single regex. Reason being, this one example contains one difference, email/outlook. Actually, there are a bunch of differences so there will be 2 regex for each difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Apache httpd config that should work:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/outlook$        https://example.com/email.aspx  [P,L]
RewriteRule   ^/([^./])/?$      https://example.com/$1.aspx     [P,L]
```

This uses a reverse proxy to serve pages like `email.aspx` and `foobar.aspx` when given "outlook" and "foobar" without revealing their extensions to users.

Though it looks like you're trying to go backwards for some reason. In that case, you'd want:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/email\.aspx$    https://example.com/outlook     [L]
RewriteRule   ^/([^.]+)\.aspx$  https://example.com/$1          [L]
```

Regex [conditional expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) cannot perform your task. The structure of a regex conditional is:

```bash
(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

- `condition` is either

  - a zero-width assertion (typically a lookahead)
  - a parenthesized integer, denoting whether that numbered capture has content
  - a capture group name in angle brackets or single quotes
  - `(R)` which is true when evaluated inside a recursion or eval
- `yes-pattern` is a regex to match given the condition is true
- `no-pattern` is an optional regex to match given the condition is false

Therefore, you can't shove new text into the match using a conditional.